How to pass key property of a rendered list in React to a function via another HTML tag
How to pass the Key value of each list item via the button created inside the li tag to the function, so that i cant filter that element out and render new list.
Need to complete the handleDelete function
import { useState } from "react";

function MyComponent() {
    const [foods, setFoods] = useState(["Apple", "Orange", "Banana"])

    const handleSubmit = () => {
        const newFood = document.getElementById("input-fruit").value;
        document.getElementById("input-fruit").value = "";
        setFoods(prevFoods => ([...prevFoods, newFood]))
    }

    const handleDelete = (idx) => {
        console.log(idx);

        // setFoods(foods.filter((el, idx) => console.log(idxx, idx)))
    }
    return (<>
        <ul>
            {foods.map((el, idx) => <li key={idx}> {el} <button key={idx} onClick={(idx) => handleDelete(idx)}>{`${idx}`}</button> </li>)}
        </ul>

        <input id="input-fruit" type="text" placeholder="Enter a food item" />
        <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
    </>);
}

export default MyComponent


Your question is unclear, you are already passing idx to handleDelete

on consol loging the idx i am getting SyntheticBaseEvent as output in the console

handleDelete has a closure on foods, you will want to use the callback variant of setState, eg.   setFoods(foods => foods.filter.......

@Keith could you please complete the filter function

Sure -> const handleDelete = idx => setFoods(foods => foods.filter((_,ix) => idx !== ix));

{foods.map((el, idx) => <li key={idx}> {el} <button key={idx} onClick={(idx) => handleDelete(idx)}>{`${idx}`}</button> </li>)}

You're using the map callback as el and idx, but you're defining the onClick arrow function as (idx) =>.
The onClick will get the click event as first param, but you're overwriting that.
If you don't need the click event, just use an empty arrow () => 
{
    foods.map((el, idx) => (
        <li key={idx}> 
            {el} 
            <button key={idx} onClick={() => handleDelete(idx)}>{`${idx}`}</button> 
        </li>
     )
}


For the handleDelete function, you can splice the array to remove it by index:


const { useState } = React;

function MyComponent() {
    const [foods, setFoods] = useState(["Apple", "Orange", "Banana"])

    const handleSubmit = () => {
        const newFood = document.getElementById("input-fruit").value;
        document.getElementById("input-fruit").value = "";
        setFoods(prevFoods => ([...prevFoods, newFood]))
    }

    const handleDelete = (idx) => {
        setFoods(prev => {
            let cpy = [...prev];
            cpy.splice(idx, 1);
            return cpy;
        })
    }
    return (<React.Fragment>
        <ul>
            {foods.map((el, idx) => <li key={idx}> {el} <button key={idx} onClick={() => handleDelete(idx)}>{`${idx}`}</button> </li>)}
        </ul>

        <input id="input-fruit" type="text" placeholder="Enter a food item" />
        <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
    </React.Fragment>);
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, document.getElementById("react"));
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>




The onClick handler is updated to onClick={() => handleDelete(idx)}. This ensures the correct index is passed when the button is clicked.
Inside handleDelete, the setFoods function filters out the item at the specified index.
The filter function compares the current index of the item (index) with the index you want to delete (idx). If they don't match, the item remains in the array.
You don't need to set a key on the button itself; it’s only necessary for the li elements to maintain uniqueness in the rendered list.

import { useState } from "react";

function MyComponent() {
    const [foods, setFoods] = useState(["Apple", "Orange", "Banana"]);

    const handleSubmit = () => {
        const newFood = document.getElementById("input-fruit").value;
        document.getElementById("input-fruit").value = "";
        setFoods(prevFoods => [...prevFoods, newFood]);
    };

    const handleDelete = (idx) => {
        setFoods(foods.filter((_, index) => index !== idx));
    };

    return (
        <>
            <ul>
                {foods.map((el, idx) => (
                    <li key={idx}>
                        {el} <button onClick={() => handleDelete(idx)}>Delete</button>
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ul>

            <input id="input-fruit" type="text" placeholder="Enter a food item" />
            <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
        </>
    );
}

export default MyComponent;


I suppose you want to delete the item when the user clicks on it, right?
In this case, you seem to have one problem in this button <button key={idx} onClick={(idx) => handleDelete(idx)}>{${idx}}</button>
The idx being passed to onClick function that way is not actually index it is the event element, the event element is where we get the clicked element using event.trigger if you are familiar with it.
To solve this remove idx from the onClick function:


<button key={idx} onClick={() => handleDelete(idx)}>{`${idx}`}</button>




which is the correct way to pass my event object with idx params ?
<button key={idx} onClick={(event, idx) => handleDelete(event, idx)}>{${idx}}</button>
OR
<button key={idx} onClick={(idx) => handleDelete(event, idx)}>{${idx}}</button>
I try to console.log(idx) in handleDelete Function, it is always undefined
